# Trouble figuring out ValueError with json, requests, BeautifulSoup: ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting this ValueError... To give some context, I'm scraping a sites json data using requests, BeautifulSoup and json with python.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for this URL. I've done it with several other URLs with no issue. Even 'page 2' (http://hypem.com/playlist/loved/Bigdirtyian/json/2/data.js) is successfully scraped and stored in a dictionary.

I've included the iPython input / output (both the problematic URL and the successful one - page 3 & 2, resp.):

```
In [1]: url = 'http://hypem.com/playlist/loved/Bigdirtyian/json/3/data.js'

In [2]: import json

In [3]: import requests

In [4]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [5]: r = requests.get(url)

In [6]: content = r.content

In [7]: soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

In [8]: page_json_dict = json.loads(str(soup))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-18cc0e11884e> in <module>()
----> 1 page_json_dict = json.loads(str(soup))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    367         end = _w(s, end).end()
    368         if end != len(s):
--> 369             raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
    370         return obj
    371 

ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 18924 - line 1 column 18932 (char 18923 - 18931)

In [9]: url2 = 'http://hypem.com/playlist/loved/Bigdirtyian/json/2/data.js'

In [10]: r2 = requests.get(url2)

In [11]: content2 = r2.content

In [12]: soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content2, 'html.parser')

In [13]: page_json_dict2 = json.loads(str(soup2))

In [14]: //
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code errors is pretty obvious if you look at the error and what `str(soup)` looks like, you can see `</a></a>` is added at the end which means you have invalid json.

It makes no sense whatsoever to try to use *json.loads* on the *Beautifulsoup* object, if you were calling it on anything it would be *.content* but the correct solution is just to call .json.

```
page_json_dict = r.json()
```

Comment: I'm still pretty new at programming and sometimes when I get something to work I run with it even though it may not be the optimal solution. Regardless, that worked so I appreciate the help despite it coming with an unnecessary amount of hostility... But thank you! :)

Comment: @zacheism, there is zero hostility, it really does not make sense to convert to soup and then to json, also if you look at the traceback you can see `char 18923 - 18931`, that tells you exactly where the problem lies so if you `print(str(soup[18923:18931]))`  that will show you what caused the error.

Comment: well in that case I apologize. I was using soup because that's kinda how i learned requests and because it's used for other reasons in the script (not shown here). But ah see I didn't know / think to do that. And even so, I don't think I would've realized that the double end anchor tag would mean invalid json - what is the reason for that? And also, why does the solution change that?

Comment: @zacheism, bs4 is adding the anchor tag, why exactly I don't know, each parser can parse your source differently.  If you just use what is returned from the request then there will be no danger of any erroneous data being added. The format is invalid as if you think about it what should json return for the anchor at the end of a dict?

Comment: closing curly bracket. yup makes a lot of sense.... guess that is pretty obvious ;) thanks again (for the schooling as well)!

Comment: No worries, happy scraping.